# Same sentence with different punctuation resulting in different meanings

Tags: punctuation, sentence-meaning

**(1)** *While the thought of an affectation for vanity's sake, on the surface, elicits shame, I have to remember I was a different person then.*

This sentence appears to imply that the result of the affectation is to, on a surface level, elicit shame.

**(2)**  *While the thought of an affectation for vanity's sake on the surface elicits shame, I have to remember I was a different person then.*

This sentence seems like it could be referring to a surface affectation for vanity's sake. Although there are better ways to write it to get that message across. Is there any reason grammatically It can't be interpreted as such?

Comment: They both refer to superficial affectation, not eliciting superficial shame. Also, all affectation is on the surface and for vanity's sake, by definition.

Comment: So, to make it better understood, it would be better to say, "While the thought of displaying an affectation elicits a superficial shame."? This way, we avoid the redundancy of a vain affectation because all affectations are vain. It also makes it clear it elicits a surface-level shame--not a superficial affectation, which is also redundant.